# Can't connect to gcloud SQL - ETIMEDOUT

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I keep getting an `ETIMEDOUT` error when connecting to a new Google Cloud SQL postgres instance. Nothing much to explain honestly. It has a public IP with public connections enabled. I'm using the default `postgres` user and the initial password I set for it. I'm connecting with the IP it gives me and port `5432`, and I've tried connecting from multiple different clients and get the same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Connection Timeout usually means a firewall issue. Is your IP address whitelisted by Cloud SQL? Tip: use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy so that your connections are authorized and encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Cloud SQL doesn't allow anyone on the internet to reach your public IP instance. Instead, you have to either configure Authorized Networks or use the Cloud SQL Proxy or a Cloud SQL Connector.

I'd recommend either running the Cloud SQL Proxy on your machine (requires gcloud with active credentials) or to configure an Authorized Network with whatever originating IP your machine uses.

See the docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-auth-proxy
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks